# Question about the length of certificate of an polynommial-time verifier

Tags: polynomial-time

We defined a polynomial-time verifier so that it has certificates of length AT MOST p(|x|) for some fixed polynomial p.

Why does it not make a difference to require a certificate $c$ to have EXACLTY length p(|x|)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a variable-length certificate $c$, you can always modify the certificate to have the form $\text{len}(c), c, 00\cdots 0$ where you append enough zeros to pad it out to the max length, thus yielding a fixed-length certificate.